# Easily generating QR codes

Tags: browser, browser-addons, qr-code

What is the easiest way to generate QR codes? When I [do a google search](https://www.google.nl/search?q=generate+QR+code), lots of different sites pop up, but usually they have lots of things to fill in, and lots of options to go through. What I want is just to create a simple text-based QR code.

I want to use this to more easily share URLs and copy/pasted text from my desktop to my smartphone, by simply generating the QR code and scanning it right from my desktop monitor with my phone. I want to make sharing between devices as easy as possible, so the fewer steps, the better it is.

What would be the easiest way to generate these QR codes? Would I need to install an extension? Or a desktop app? Or is there an easier way?

Comment: `I want to use this to more easily share URLs and copy/pasted text from my desktop to my smartphone` - My solution was just to setup an internet messenger client on my smartphone and desktop.

Comment: @Zoredache I guess that would work too, yeah :P

Comment: I usually use this: http://zxing.appspot.com/generator/ change to URL, copy and paste that and click on generate. Another idea that you can do (on top of Zoredache's recommendation), you could also use Chrome History as Chrome do sync the history of multiple devices that are signed in with the same account. So you can see your desktop history on your phone, and vice versa.

Comment: You could use https://www.google.com/bookmarks/ to save URLs once (via a bookmarklet on your desktop browser) and access it on multiple devices

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I think is by far the easiest way to do this, is to simply create a custom search engine (Chrome/Opera) or bookmark shortcut (Firefox), with `qr` as keyword. This will allow you to generate a QR code by just typing `qr Foo Bar Baz` in your URL bar.

For this search engine then, you can use a simple and fast public QR API, such as the following:

```
http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chs=200x200&cht=qr&chld=|1&chl=%s
http://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?size=200x200&data=%s
```

Both of these will result in a 200x200px QR code, and although both these APIs will return a different QR code, they will both decode to the original string, with roughly the same amount of data-loss recovery.

See https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/infographics/docs/overview and http://qrserver.com/api/documentation/create-qr-code/ respectively for the documentation on both of those URLs. As you can see, the latter also allows some extra functionality such as `bgcolor` and `color`. So, I think it's probably better to use QRServer instead of using Google's [deprecated](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/infographics/) charts.

## Setting up shortcut bookmarks or search engines

You can set up these search engines and bookmarks in a couple of different ways for different browsers. It shouldn't be too hard for either of the listed ones though. Internet Explorer does not support this, and for as far as I could find on the internet, Safari doesn't either, other than what [this guide](http://www.tuaw.com/2012/10/12/mac-101-safari-bookmark-shortcuts/) explains (which seems to be something slightly different).

### Google Chrome

In Chrome you can create a new search engine for this going to , where you can pick between the 2 urls listed above. This is based . You can also manually add the search engine via the following steps:

1. Either **use [this JSBin](http://jsbin.com/mowip/1/)** to easily select one of the two options listed above (JSBin code is based on [the code provided here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21606138/1256925))
2. Or **go to `chrome://settings/searchEngines`**, and in the window that shows up, scroll to the bottom, and enter:

   - In the first input box, enter the search engine's description ("QR Code" for example)
   - In the second input box, enter the keyword that triggers the search engine ("qr" for example)
   - In the third input box, enter the target URL, with the part you're going to be typing in replaced with `%s` (the URLs listed above are already in this format)

Keep in mind that if you've got automatic search suggestion enabled (like Google's suggestions), this may interfere with the shorter keywords. To fix this, you can just change the keyword to `qr.` since the period behind it will stop Chrome from treating it like a search phrase automatically.

### Firefox

Firefox uses bookmarks instead of search engines, but the end result is the exact same.

You can create a shortcut bookmark in one of two simple ways:

**Method 1:**

1. Go directly to the base URL:

   - http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chs=200x200&cht=qr&chld=|1&chl=%s
   - http://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?size=200x200&data=%s
   - ***Note:*** If these links show an error, just ignore it. It's caused by the occurrence of `%s` in the URL, but after setting up the bookmarks this won't be a problem.
2. Press Ctrl+D to create the bookmark
3. A popup window will show up. In it, enter:

   - In the top input box, enter the bookmark's description ("QR Code" for example)
   - In the bottom input box, enter the keyword that triggers the bookmark ("qr" for example).
   - Since you created the bookmark on the url containing `%s` already, you don't have to do anything else to configure the URL.

**Method 2:**

1. Create a bookmark anywhere, and configure it
2. Press Ctrl+D anywhere to create a dummy bookmark
3. See step 3 for the first method
4. Open the bookmark's properties:

   - If you saved it to the toolbar, right click it and select the bottom option (Properties)
   - If you saved it to anywhere other than the toolbar, open your bookmarks interface via Ctrl+Shift+B, and simply select it.
5. In the second input box of the bookmark's properties (Location), change the url to the url you want to use.

### Opera

Opera, like Chrome, uses search engines too, but unlike Chrome, you'll have to do it via the settings:

1. Press Ctrl+F12 to open the Preferences window
2. Go to the Search tab (middle tab)
3. Press the "Add..." button (top button), and enter:

   - In the top input box, enter the search engine's description ("QR Code" for example)
   - In the second input box, enter the keyword that triggers the bookmark ("qr" for example)
   - In the third input box, enter the target URL, with the part you're going to be typing in replaced with `%s` (the URLs listed above are already in this format)
   - *If there is no third input in this window, press the button to the right of the input box that says "Details > >" to show further options.*

---

I hope this helps at least some people. I've told a couple of people I know about this, and most of them found it useful, so I decided to create this post so that others might find it useful too.